# Baisser/lever la « glace » pour la « vitre » d'une automobile : détails ?

Tags: usage, québec, fréquence-utilisation

> Une auto [...] passa lentement devant lui, les glaces à demi baissées,
> enveloppée dans le battement forcené d'une musique disco (Y.
> Beauchemin, 1989, ds. le dictionnaire [Usito](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/glace))

Pour moi (Montréal), *baisser/lever la glace* pour parler d'une *vitre* d'une automobile est complètement inusité. Mais la citation est d'un auteur Québécois, donc je suis perplexe. Il n'y a aucune note sur l'usage, ni sur Usito, ni dans la BDL d'après ma recherche.

- Cet emploi de *glace* est-il partout en usage dans la francophonie
  (excluant le Québec) et est-il plus fréquent que *vitre* dans le
  contexte de l'automobile ?

et/ou ;

- Au Québec, l'emploi de *glace* pour *vitre* est-il standard et
  uniforme dans ce même contexte ?

Answer (score 3):

On a aussi les mots *essuie-glace* et *lave-glace*, tout à fait courants, et que je n'ai jamais entendus comme *essuie-vitre* et *lave-vitre*. Ceux-là ont l'air bien figés.

Mais à part ces deux mots, il semble que *vitre* est en train de supplanter *glace* dans le contexte de l'automobile (cf aussi requêtes similaires sur google ngrams). *Lever la glace* et *baisser la glace* ne me semblent pas très courants en France métropolitaine de part mon expérience non plus.

[image]

Comment: En appui: Dans mon enfance (milieu du siècle dernier) je disais et on disait autour de moi "lever/baisser les glaces" de la voiture. Je ne dis plus ça depuis je ne sais pas quand... toujours est-il que depuis longtemps les glaces sont devenues des vitres.

Comment: J'étais tellement stupéfait par la locution avec le verbe que j'avais oublié les mots composés avec _lave-/essuie-_. Pour _lave-_ j'accepte aussi avec [_vitre_](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/8870044/liquide-lave-glace), mais pas pour _essuie-_. Donc ici ce serait simplement que le lexique ne semble pas encore avoir identifié que c'est essentiellement _vieilli_. On m'a montré ça dans une doc. très récente et ça faisait jaser... on pensait que l'explication c'était que c'était courant en France. Et la Belgique ?

Comment: @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t Oui, confirmé pour _lave-vitre_, mais plutôt dans _produit lave-vitre_ en dehors du contexte automobile?

Comment: De façon générale, "glace" pour "vitre" est vieilli. C'est légèrement plus courant pour "miroir", mais là aussi je pense que l'usage se perd. Par contre il est vrai qu'on décrit traditionnellement les voitures par leur nombre de "glaces" : les coupés ont 1 glace, les coachs 2, les berlines 2 ou 3 et les limousines 3 ou 4.